# more than one content type in a condition?

Tags: 8, nodes

I'm using this as below described in my subtheme (Thanks to @4k4 and @Berdir):

```
function kanu_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if($variables['node']->getType() != 'test') {
    return;
 }
  $field = $variables['node']->field_where_to_publish;

  if (!$field->isEmpty() && $field->entity->label() == 'public') {
     $variables['display_submitted'] = FALSE;
     $variables['content']['comment']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

How to write it for 3 different content type (with same field names)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in_array`.

```
$types = array('one', 'two', 'three');

if (!in_array($variables['node']->getType(), $types)) {
  // code
}
```

Comment: This is more compact than using `||`, I will start using this trick.

Comment: Can do either or, I just do it this way because it reads easier just checking an array.

Comment: see above. Sorry,it doeskin' t work. 2 types: test, information_mit_arisstext